# How to increase the fps and resulotion of OpenCV Android realtime image process app?

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv

I used Android Studio 3.4.2 and OpenCV 3.4.5

Note: Now I have only camera displaying app and now its resolution and fps is low. I don't know what will be its fps when I added it to image processing lines and files.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question pertains to [cv::videoCapture](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html), you can change properties such as resolution and frame rate using [set](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a8c6d8c2d37505b5ca61ffd4bb54e9a7c). The various supported properties are defined [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704d). In your case, you would want to test what values your hardware support for `CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH`, `CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT` and `CAP_PROP_FPS`.